# Perl CGI print format

Tags: perl, cgi

I've run into a rather odd problem. I'm simply trying to display comments the user has entered by looping through the arrays that store the name entered, and the commented associated with that name.

```
#Check through each name
        for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar @$namesRef; $i++ )
        {
            #Display the comment to the user
            print @$namesRef[$i].": ".@$commentsRef[$i], p; 
        }
```

On the page where the comments are displays, rather than displaying them like 'John: comment' it displays it like 'Johncomment:'. Also, the ',p' is not included so the next comment doesn't go to a new line.

I would put up an image to better show what the problem is, but I don't have enough rep yet :/

EDIT: The @-signs are there since these are references to arrays outside of this subroutine.

EDIT: The initial arrays are declared in this subroutine.

sub buildForm
{
    my $form = shift; #Check which button was pressed.

```
my $daysOld = 0; #Holds how many days old the user is.
my $commentErrors = 0;

my @names = ();
my @comments =(); #Array to store the user's comments.
my @errorMessages =(); #Array to store the error messages for the current form.
```

The following is where the subroutine for the comment form is called:

```
elsif ( $form == 3 )
{
    &readComments(\@comments, \@names, \@errorMessages); #Read in the comments.
    #Initial build - Can't have any errors.
    &build3(\@comments,\@names, \@errorMessages, $commentErrors, param('name'), param('comment'));
}
elsif ( $form == 4 )
{
    $commentErrors = &commentFormErrorCheck( param('name'), param('comment'), \@errorMessages ); #Check for an errors.
    &build3(\@comments,\@names, \@errorMessages, $commentErrors, param('name'), param('comment'));
}
```

Comment: In this context you do not need `&` before your sub calls.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the use of the @-signs in the print statement.

Assuming `@names` and `@comments` are parallel arrays, showing a full simplified example to demonstrate usage:

```
build3(\@comments, \@names);

sub build3 {
    my $comments = shift;
    my $names = shift;
    for (my $i = 0; $i < @$names; $i++) {
        print $names->[$i].": ".$comments->[$i], p;
    }
}
```

That said, you might want to take a look at `printf` to make that line more readable.

Also, don't forget about HTML escaping.

EDIT:

Adding an example using HTML escaping and `printf()`.

```
use CGI qw/escapeHTML p/;

printf("%s: %s%s\n", escapeHTML($names->[$i]), escapeHTML($comments->[$i]), p);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that these are references to arrays outside of the subroutine. That's why the @-signs are there.

Comment: @Shaun can you show the declaration and function call? It makes a difference.

Comment: @codnodder Done. If you need to see anything else let me know. Also, I have tried adding in the '->' that chrsblck mentioned. No luck.

Comment: @codnodder I tried using printf() still no luck. What's odd is that it's putting the name and the comment together, with no spacing, and then just putting the colon at the end.

Comment: @Shaun Try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($names);`. There has to be something going on with your input arrays.